# Why would it not be good to have a test case step tell you to repeat a previous step again?

Tags: testing, testcase

Let's say I have a test case with some steps in it. Now, let's say that step 3 needs to be repeated after you complete steps 4 and 5 ... so that when you do step 6 you are in the right place.

Is it good practice to tell the tester to repeat a step? Or would it be better copy-and-paste the repeated step into the step where you would need to repeat it?

I am hearing arguments that it is not industry standard to tell the tester to repeat steps and that one might not pass certain certifications if test cases are written in this manner.

**Example:**

*Step 1: Click the View Event Log button; Expected Results: Event Log window appears

Step 2: Close the event log window (X) or OK; Expected Results: The Event Log window disappears

Step 3: Repeat Step 1; Expected Results: Expected Results from Step 1

Step 4: Click the Cancel button; Expected Results: The Event Log window closes and any changes (such as clearing the log) are not applied

Step 5: Repeat Step 1; Expected Results: Expected Results from Step 1

Step 6: Click the Clear button and hit apply; Expected Results: The log is cleared

...*

Some people think that I should be copying-and-pasting what is in Step 1 each time I need to repeat that step rather than just simply saying that the tester should repeat the step. Any input as to industry standards, potential downfalls, etc ... would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess nobody likes this question. I couldn't find a StackOverflow-like website for testers so I just posted here.

Comment: So you people want this closed? Where should I post this in order to get some response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test case design does not really follow an industry standard, if you were trying to get certified, listing to repeat a step is a no-no.  I personally think that's crap. I see no problem asking a tester to repeat a step.  As a believer in agile methodology, I prefer much simpler test cases so a tester has more time to test scenarios rather than design test cases (or a developer more time to develop if you are in a cross functional team).  If your looking for more input from a larger testing community try http://www.qaforums.com/

Answer (score 0):

Test cases should be as independent as possible and not verifying two outcomes in a single test case. The test cases should not be designed in a way where the tester has to repeat any previous step. In this case, a new test case should be written because it is a new path. The prons for this approach is that at the end of execution you'll have a clear picture of the test coverage and the pass/fail % of the requirements because all the test cases are independent.